# Got "else" with no preceding "if" error ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

## links

```
- if current_user
= link_to "Edit", edit_job_path(@job), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"
= link_to "Delete", job_path(@job), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"

- else

 = link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"
```

This returns:

```
Got "else" with no preceding "if" error ruby
```

Why is that?

Comment: due to indentation

Comment: lets try the given solution below

Answer (score 7):

Although it is not clearly stated in the question, I assume it is supposed to be a haml file.

It is because the body after the first `if` line is not indented. So the `if` body is parsed as empty. The `else` line then starts on its own.

Comment: You mean "haml file"?

Comment: @MarekLipka Right. Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

```
- if current_user
  = link_to "Edit", edit_job_path(@job), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"
  = link_to "Delete", job_path(@job), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"

- else

  = link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"
```

Comment: @Anthony feel free to accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: Inconsistent indentation: 2 spaces used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 1 tab. Getting this error while running that?